# Get mongodb collection name with Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, mongodb-query

Here's my DB and collections
[image]

I want to show it through CodeIgniter framework,
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: please write code instead of image.

Comment: You need to do some preliminary set up before you can write code. First see [this tutorial](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Using-MongoDB-in-Codeigniter) and get CodeIgniter set up.

Comment: what's code ?@Ali

Comment: I've already read it but i still didn't understand how to get that collections @Jamie_D